# WinAPI - How do I interpret a bitmask of 0 (LMShare.h/STYPE_DISKTREE)?

Tags: winapi

I'm working with the [NetShareEnum function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the Windows API.  It can return the [SHARE_INFO_2 structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  That structure contains the `shi2_type` member, which is defined as "a bitmask of flags that specify the type of the shared resource".  The values of the bitmask are defined in LMSHare.h

```
#define STYPE_DISKTREE       0    // Disk drive.
#define STYPE_PRINTQ         1    // Print queue.
#define STYPE_DEVICE         2    // Communication device.
#define STYPE_IPC            3    // Interprocess communication (IPC).
```

I don't know how to interpret `STYPE_DISKTREE`.  Since it is a bitmask of zero, I can't use a bitwise AND on the mask and compare it against the mask to see if it is set.  That is,

```
(shi2_type & STYPE_DISKTREE) == STYPE_DISKTREE
```

is always true.  Is this intended to mean that all shares are inherently disk shares?  Or, should I make this a special case and use the following comparison to check if the share is a disk share,

```
shi2_type == STYPE_DISKTREE
```

which is to say that a disk share is exclusively a disk share and nothing else.

Comment: It looks like this is an exclusive mask (at least in the low-order bits) because 1 and 3 are both used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A bitmask of flags that specify the type of the shared resource. Calls to the NetShareSetInfo function ignore this member.
>
> **One** of the following flags may be specified.
>
> STYPE_DISKTREE
>
> STYPE_PRINTQ
>
> STYPE_DEVICE
>
> STYPE_IPC
>
> In addition, one or both of the following flags may be specified.
>
> STYPE_SPECIAL
>
> STYPE_TEMPORARY

So the low part of shi2_type will be one of DISKTREE, PRINTQ, DEVICE, or IPC and the high part may contain SPECIAL and/or TEMPORARY.  Sadly the documentation is not explicit about the size of the parts, but since there's only 4 types you can just take the low byte.  You could also just drop the high byte as that is where the 2 flags are defined.

Comment: Thanks.  I got so hung up on the use of the term bitmask that I missed that part.

Comment: The `STYPE_MASK` value can be used to isolate the `DISKTREE`/`PRINTQ`/`DEVICE`/`IPC` part.

Comment: Incomplete documentation strikes again.